# python 3 class import error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my project setup directories.

```
 ~Desktop/WoodCutterBuddy
    tests.py
    WoodCutterBuddy.py
    WoodCutterBuddy_api.py
```

I imported woodCutterBuddy  into `test.py` but I have the following error

[image]

[image]

any idea what's the problem? than you in advance

Comment: Well, is there a function or class named `woodcutterbuddy` in `WoodCutterBuddy.py`?

Comment: yes it  has a class name WoodCutterBuddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using

```
from woodCutterBuddy import woodcutterbuddy, knapsack
```

the woodcutterbuddy and knapsack must be defined in the file
    WoodCutterBuddy.py

And this method is also not recmended because when you will use it e.g knapsack in your code, and someone else read your code it might be difficult to easily trace back where it is defined (without help of python IDE)
the better approach is import as

```
import WoodCutterBuddy
```

and use it as

```
WoodCutterBuddy.knapsack
```